# Remix Error Error: Directory import '/app/build' is not supported resolving ES modules

Tags: javascript, typescript, remix

I'm getting an ESM module error when using the remix framework:
`Error: Directory import '/app/build' is not supported resolving ES modules imported from /app/node_modules/@remix-run/serve/dist/cli.js Did you mean to import /app/build/index.js?`

It doesn't appear when I run the dev server or build it. But it does have the error when I run it in Docker (my docker file https://gist.github.com/BKG01/afd1b2745fab27763fd8b69d71ab06f0)

Any idea how I can resolve it?

If I run
`node node_modules/.bin/remix-serve build` 
directly (outside of docker) I also get the same error.

Comment: https://github.com/remix-run/remix/discussions/7586

Answer (score 2):

Changing the command to `remix-serve ./build/index.js` fixed the issue (ESM can't yet import modules.